# File output With roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I just have a simple question on which i'm stuck for a few days :
I have a node in which I output a hand written log file using the c++ functions from fstream.

When i'm starting it using rosrun, my file are correctly generated.
However, using a rosrun is not practical when you want to use topics rename and I wanted to make it generic and to launch it with a roslaunch.
However, it appears that, when I start it with the roslaunch, I don't suceed anymore to write my output files.

I looked into the output option from the roslaunch, "screen" or "log" ( default) are available but in the doc it's written that they should redirect stdout/stderr (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) and not other custom outputs.

If you have any solution or any idee to fix it, I will welcome them with pleasure =D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266181/file-output-with-roslaunch/) by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 267 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-12**:
Can you check whether you can find the files in `$HOME/.ros`?

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-07-13**:
can you post your node?

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-07-13**:
It's indeed in my $HOME/.ros which, in my opnion shouldn't be but ti's there, thanks a lot for your answer, waiting for you for a fewdays if you want to make an answer below ;)

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-07-13**:
And I will add a question since it's not very practical, Would you have an idee on how to change it's location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It's indeed in my $HOME/.ros which, in my opnion shouldn't be but ti's there [..]

Please see #q235337.

Best practice is to use absolute paths, not relative ones.

Use parameters (and `rospack find ..`) to be able to keep flexibility.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-07-13**:
Thanks =D
So the relative paths work with "direct" rosrun calls but not with roslaunch ones. Currently looking into your link for more details ! Thanks once more